# Problema con la posición en p5.js

Tags: javascript, redes-neuronales, p5js

Estoy usando este código en p5js :

```js
//Variables//
   
var p;
var points = new Array(200);
var cambiarEcuacion = false;

//Funciones//

function mousePressed() {
  if (cambiarEcuacion) {
    cambiarEcuacion = false;
  } else {
    cambiarEcuacion = true;
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  p = new Perceptron(3);

  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    points[i] = new Point();
  }

  frameRate(1);
}


function draw() {
  background(255);

  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var pt = points[i];
    var inpt = [pt.x, pt.y, 1];
    var target = pt.label;
    p.train(inpt,target);
  }

  stroke(51);
  var pt1 = new Point(-1, f(-1));
  var pt2 = new Point(1, f(1));
  line(pt1.pixelX(), pt1.pixelY(), pt2.pixelX(), pt2.pixelY());
  var pt3 = new Point(-1, p.guessY(-1));
  var pt4 = new Point(1, p.guessY(1));
  stroke(255,0,0);
  line(pt3.pixelX(), pt3.pixelY(), pt4.pixelX(), pt4.pixelY());
  stroke(51);

  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var pt = points[i];
    var inpt = [pt.x, pt.y, 1];
    var g = p.guess(inpt);
    points[i].show(g);
    if (g == points[i].label) {
      fill(0, 255, 0);
    } else {
      fill(255, 0, 0);
    }
    var px = points[i].pixelX();
    var py = points[i].pixelY();
    ellipse(px, py, 8, 8);
  }
}


function sign(n) {
  if (n > 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}

function f(x) {
  return 0.3*x;
}


class Perceptron {
  constructor(n) {
    this.weights = new Array(n);
    for (var i = 0; i < this.weights.length; i++) {
      this.weights[i] = random(-1, 1);
    }
    this.lr = 0.01;
  }

  guess(input) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.weights.length; i++) {
      sum += input[i] * this.weights[i];
    }
    var output = sign(sum);
    return output;
  }

  train(input, target) {
    var guess = this.guess(input);
    var error = target - guess;

    for (var i = 0; i < this.weights.length; i++) {
      this.weights[i] += error * input[i] * this.lr;
    }
  }

  guessY(x) {
    var w0 = this.weights[0];
    var w1 = this.weights[1];
    var w2 = this.weights[2];
    if (cambiarEcuacion) { // Si haces click se puede ver la diferencia entre si está el w2 o no
      return (w0*x)/-w1;
    } else {
     return (w2+w0*x)/-w1; 
    }    
  }
}

class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    if (x) {this.x = x} else {this.x = random(-1, 1)}
    if (y) {this.y = y} else {this.y = random(-1, 1)}

    var lineY = f(this.x);
    if (this.y > lineY) {
      this.label = 1;
    } else {
      this.label = -1;
    }
  }

  pixelX() {
    return map(this.x, -1, 1, 0, width);
  }

  pixelY() {
    return map(this.y, -1, 1, height, 0);
  }

  show(n) {
    stroke(51)
    if (n == 1) {
      fill(255);
    } else {
      fill(0);
    }
    var px = this.pixelX();
    var py = this.pixelY();
    ellipse(px, py, 16, 16);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  padding:0px;
};
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.1/p5.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Está ligeramente modificado de un código que creó TheCodingTrain (Daniel Shiffman) pero supuestamente debería crearse una línea donde el "Perceptron" cree que está la línea, pero lo hace de forma equivocada.

El problema está en que tengo otro código modificado de su github que si me funciona, pero querría saber que es lo que está mal entre el primer código y el segundo, ya que yo no encuentro diferencia en la parte de adivinar donde está la línea (en el draw(), donde están los puntos con el guessY())

Segundo Código: https://editor.p5js.org/Clipi/sketches/cCBGnFzDi (En el editor, el Perceptron está en el archivo "a.js")

Comment: Podrías explicar un poco más lo que estás haciendo? Qué son los puntos, los colores que se ven y la línea que se dibuja?

Comment: @PabloLozano Claro!! estoy intentando hacer una Neural Network que intente adivinar si los puntos están en un lado o en otro de la línea roja pero no se por qué no funciona implementando el bias... los datos se "desorientan" y ponen la línea mucho más abajo o arriba

Comment: Si quito w2 de la formula, funciona correctamente, pero esa no puede ser la solución, porque simplemente estoy quitando el "bias" de en medio, y aunque así me vale, me gustaría saber solucionarlo.(He editado la publicación, si haces click se puede ver la diferencia entre si la ecuación tiene o no w2) Espero que esto pueda servir como pista

Comment: Yo lo veo funcionando bien, ahora mismo: los puntos debajo de la línea de un color y los puntos de encima con otro. Los que parecen dudosos tienen el centro rojo durante unas iteraciones....

Comment: Tienen el punto rojo si la Neural netwok falla, y verde si acierta donde está la linea. La linea NEGRA es la real, la ROJA es la que la Neural Network cree que es. Si no te sale ninguna linea ROJA es porque la tendras activada la ecuacion con w2... Mira mi ultimo comentario

Comment: Entonces lo que intentas es que las dos sean la misma? o que los puntos se coloreen en base a la línea roja (supongo que la diferencia entre ambas líneas es el *bias* del que hablas)